# Where can I find piano samples (mono not stereo)

Tags: audio-recording, piano

I just can't find this anywhere on the Internet!  Google is drawing a blank!

I'm looking for a set of 88 piano notes, preferably in .WAV.  But MONO!

I found:
http://bedroomproducersblog.com/2010/07/01/free-sample-shootout-3-acoustic-electric-and-toy-pianos/

but not one of those links offers what I am after.   The closest is http://theremin.music.uiowa.edu/MIS.html  which is recorded in stereo.

I need mono!  Someone somewhere must have made such a recording!

Does anyone know of such a resource?

π

PS If it is a subset, say 30 notes out of the full 88, then I'm still interested!

Comment: Why not just combine the two channels from the stereo one you found and you will have mono?

Comment: I've tried, and it doesn't sound clean.

Comment: There was a youtube phenomenon when people were recording themselves playing one note at the time and then combining these recordings to make compositions. I think if you were to find such a person and contact them, they might be willing to provide their originals.

Comment: Also, since you say combining left and right sounds dirty, perhaps splitting them, and using just one may sound reasonably good.

Comment: If it sounds bad with both stereo channels combined then the recording of the samples wasn't done with a proper stereo setup. Mono compatibility remains an important goal in professional recording; a well-sampled piano should certainly sound ok in mono as well.